# Sticky position in Safari with Angular Components

Tags: angular, safari, sticky

So, `position: sticky` is awesome, right? And so is Angular, right? Using both in conjunction with Firefox and Chrome work great. The problem starts with Safari.

If you build an Angular component that has a `position: sticky` div within it as the first element in the template, Safari doesn't know how to handle it. Example:

**AppComponent:**

```
@Component({
  template: '<sticky-component></sticky-component>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**StickyComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sticky-component',
  template: '<div class="sticky">Should be sticky</div>',
  styles: [
    `
      .sticky {
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class StickyComponent {}
```

This will generate a DOM like:

```
...
<sticky-component>
  <div class="sticky"></div>
</sticky-component>
...
```

If you physically write out the HTML *without* the `<sticky-component>` it works great in Safari. But since the parent of the sticky element is the host element, this fails. Trying to add the sticky CSS to the host element doesn't seem like it works either. Has anyone run into this issue before or has any solution? I know I can implement this sticky functionality using event listeners within Angular, but `position: sticky` is sooo much easier.

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jede8a (works in Chrome/Firefox but not in Safari)

Comment: can you reproduce this in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Updated with StackBlitz.

Comment: your missing a dot before sticky, it's pointing to element <sticky> now, it's correct in stackblitz

Answer (score 5):

<sup><sub>This is more of a workaround which might not suit your needs but I guess it deserves an answer since it *does* solve the problem (not necessarily in the way you'd like it).</sub></sup>

If the issue with Safari is a custom element (with a dash) used in the DOM, you can get rid of that by specifying a different selector. Instead of

```
selector: 'sticky-component',
```

you could have

```
selector: 'div[sticky-component]',
```

and then use the component by adding an attribute.

```
<div sticky-component></div>
```

Although certainly not ideal in this use-case, this is a valid way to define components. In fact, it's often done with custom buttons -- for example, Material itself uses this pattern: `<button mat-button>`.

Comment: So this will work if I add the sticky CSS to the host element. But if I keep it as-is, with the first element within the template containing the sticky CSS, it still does not work. Viable work-around though, thank you!

Comment: Excellent.  Works great with the suggestion above from @SpellChucker  What a pain to find a solution for!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about inline styling. But if you move style to an external file. Following should do the trick.

```css
 :host {
    .sticky {
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked wrapping the sticky selector inside a `div` with the `height` property set in the template.

```js
    @Component({
        selector: 'sticky-component',
        template: 
           `<div style="height: 100%">
              <div class="sticky">Should be sticky</div>
            </div>
           `,
        styles: [
           ` .sticky {
                 position: -webkit-sticky;
                 position: sticky;
                 top: 0;
            }`
        ]
     })
     export class StickyComponent {}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of to make sticky work on safari you need to use `position: -webkit-sticky;`, but.....

After alot of testing and poking this is simply not working case for Safari when putting `position:sticky` into a nested element. A good example to check how this behaves i found was this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kganguly/pen/rrygaE/) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482893/why-does-safari-position-webkit-sticky-stick-to-an-inline-parent?rq=1) post.

There is a bug [reported](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106062) in webkit for this, it also includes a test which i've not completely understood.

So the follow up question, whats your reason to put it in a nested element? Can you work around it?

Comment: Yeah, Safari automatically adds the `-webkit-sticky` if it's not there, but you're right. That bug is slightly different than what I am experiencing, but still related. As far as why I'm doing this: I can work around it, was just wondering if this was a known issue and if there were any workarounds that I missed.